# Is this correct code in Node.js? (variable scoping)

Tags: javascript, oop, node.js

```
function user(req,res){
    var uuu = req.params.userid;
    processUserObject(uuu, function(user_object){ //This could take a long time...
        console.log(uuu); 
        res.send(JSON.stringify(user_object));
    });
};
app.get('/:userid',function(req,res){
    user(req,res);
});
```

First, assume that the site gets lots of hits. (thousands per second!)

When a user hits the page with his ID, will `console.log(uuu)` output the correct ID?  What I'm worried (in regards to variable scoping) is that when person A hits the page and goes through `processUserObject`, it could take a long time, during which person B hits the page and **changes uuu**...resulting in console.log to output person B's ID instead of person A's ID.

***Side note:*** I have this worry because when I was new to Node.js, I forgot to initialize some variables with `var`.  When my site got lots of hits, my users noticed that they were getting info from other user's hits...ouch.

Comment: A billion hits per second sounds unlikely! You would get it if every single person on earth would visit, at the same time, a page on your website every 7 seconds.

Comment: It's just in theory...I didn't mean it literally.

Comment: he could have a million servers polling his site for service requests. Each one hitting the service once a millisecond.

Comment: For context so that you can scale your "theory" correctly: Twitter receives on average 600 requests per second, Facebook about 700 per second. Yahoo averages out at 3500 per second and Google, the largest of them all gets 34000 hits per second. So anticipating more than a thousand requests per second means you're expecting your web app to be much more popular than Facebook.

Comment: "I forgot to initialize some variables with var" -- a good argument for using coffeescript :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `console.log(uuu)` will log the right value. When you say this:

```
var uuu = req.params.userid;
```

You are capturing the current value of `req.params.userid` in the local variable `uuu` and then `uuu` is captured by the callback closure. However, if you accidentally did this:

```
uuu = req.params.userid;
```

Then you'd be capturing the `req.params.userid` value in the **global** `uuu` and each of your callbacks would **share the same `uuu`** and you'd have the usual closure problem. Each of your

```
function(user_object) { ... }
```

anonymous functions are separate and distinct entities with their own separate and distinct `uuu` variables (given that you say `var uuu` rather than `uuu` of course).

BTW, if you do end up with a billion requests per second the heat from your overworked CPUs will melt the walls between this world and the next thus releasing the elder gods from R'lyeh. And if that happens, `uuu` won't matter at all.